# Button won't change value in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tic-tac-toe

I am attempting to make Tic Tac Toe using TKinter in Python. I wanted to make a function where it changes the button value and its respective position in my other 2D array based on its `__str__()` attribute that I found in its directory. Here is my function:

```
    def changed_based_on_id(self,btn):
        if btn.__str__() == '.!button' and btn['text'] == '':
            self.ld['text'] = 'X' if self.p1turn else 'O'
            self.board[0][0] = 'X' if self.p1turn else 'O'
            self.turn()
        elif btn.__str__() == '.!button2' and btn['text'] == '': 
            self.tc['text'] = 'X' if self.p1turn else 'O'
            self.board[0][1] = 'X' if self.p1turn else 'O'
            self.turn()
        elif btn.__str__() == '.!button3' and btn['text'] == '': 
            self.rd['text'] = 'X' if self.p1turn else 'O'
            self.board[0][2] = 'X' if self.p1turn else 'O'
            self.turn()
        elif btn.__str__() == '.!button4' and btn['text'] == '':
            self.cl['text'] == 'X' if self.p1turn else 'O'
            self.board[1][0] = 'X' if self.p1turn else 'O'
            self.turn()
        elif btn.__str__() == '.!button5' and btn['text'] == '':
            self.c['text'] == 'X' if self.p1turn else 'O'
            self.board[1][1] = 'X' if self.p1turn else 'O'
            self.turn()
        elif btn.__str__() == '.!button6' and btn['text'] == '':
            self.cr['text'] == 'X' if self.p1turn else 'O'
            self.board[1][2] = 'X' if self.p1turn else 'O'
            self.turn()
        elif btn.__str__() == '.!button7' and btn['text'] == '':
            self.bld['text'] == 'X' if self.p1turn else 'O'
            self.board[2][0] = 'X' if self.p1turn else 'O'
            self.turn()
        elif btn.__str__() == '.!button8' and btn['text'] == '':
            self.bc['text'] == 'X' if self.p1turn else 'O'
            self.board[2][1] = 'X' if self.p1turn else 'O'
            self.turn()
        elif btn.__str__() == '.!button9' and btn['text'] == '':
            self.brd['text'] == 'X' if self.p1turn else 'O'
            self.board[2][2] = 'X' if self.p1turn else 'O'
            self.turn()
            print(self.board)
        else:
            pass
```

When I try to press a button other than the first three, the value on the button does not change, but the 2D array position does. Have I done something wrong? I can't seem to find it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found in the documentation a function called `config()` which you can apply. It worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

For the buttons other than the first 3, you used `==` in:

```
self.cl['text'] == 'X' if self.p1turn else 'O'
```

It should be `=` instead:

```
self.cl['text'] = 'X' if self.p1turn else 'O'
```

---

Note that using variable's internal name is not a good design.  Better use a 2D list (like `self.board`) to store the buttons and use `row` and `col` to access them.

Comment: Oh, How did I not see that? Thanks! Can't believe I didn't see that. My board is oriented as such:

Comment: ld|tc|rd is the first row, then lc|c|rc, then bld|bc|brc